# Split my list into n sub-lists and print all possibilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I want to divide a list into n sub-lists and print all possible sub-lists.
n is integer input by user.
length of list can be anything
1<=n<=len(list)

```
For example 
if list = [1,2,3,4]
and n=1
solution = [1,2,3,4]
if n=2
solution=([1],[2,3,4]),([1,2],[3,4]),([1,2,3],[4])
if n=3
solution=([1],[2],[3,4]),([1,2],[3],[4]),([1],[2,3],[4])
```

Note:- brackets do not represent tuple or any other data type output can be in any form.
Ps:-This is not a code but stackoverflow forced me to format it as such
This is what I tried

''''python

```
lst=[]
lst1=[]
lst4=[]
for i in range(0,10000):
    element=int(input())
    lst.append(element)
    print("If you want to continue adding list press y else press n")
    choice=input()
    if choice=='y':
        continue
    elif choice=='n':
        break
    else:
        print("please enter a valid choice")
print("Enter division size")
N=int(input())
maxchunk=len(lst)-N+1
for j in range(maxchunk,0,-1):
    rchunk=(len(lst)-j)//(N-1)
    lst2=lst[0:j]
    lst1.append(lst2)
    chunksize=((len(lst)-j)+1)//(N-1)
    print(chunksize)
    for k in range(j,len(lst),chunksize):
        lst3=lst[k:k+chunksize]
        lst1.append(lst3)
    lst4.append(lst1)
    lst1=[]
print(lst4)
```

''''

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and show what you have tried. Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you.

Comment: Note that [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is a built-in function in Python, and you are reassigning it. You should choose a different variable name for your list

Comment: @Vladmir Fokow  Thanks for heads up I posted my attempted code just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to iterate over all the ways to choose `n-1` split points of your list:

```py
from itertools import combinations

lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
n = 3

result = []
# n-1 split points:
for indices in combinations(range(1, len(lst)), n-1):
    # indices are the indices of split points
    splits = []
    start = 0
    for stop in indices:
        splits.append(lst[start : stop])
        start = stop
    splits.append(lst[start : ])
    result.append(splits)
```

`result`:

```
[[[10], [20], [30, 40, 50]],
 [[10], [20, 30], [40, 50]],
 [[10], [20, 30, 40], [50]],
 [[10, 20], [30], [40, 50]],
 [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50]],
 [[10, 20, 30], [40], [50]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using a recursive generator function that yields all the desired partitions for a given array and number of partitions.

```py
def partition(arr, n):

  if n == 1:
    yield (arr,)

  else:
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
      for other in partition(arr[i:], n-1):
        yield (arr[:i],) + other
```

You can call this like

```
for item in partition([1,2,3,4], 3):
  print(item)
```

Which shows

```
([1], [2], [3, 4])
([1], [2, 3], [4])
([1, 2], [3], [4])
```

Or alternatively, if you want to access everything at once

```
print(list(partition([1,2,3,4], 3)))
```

Showing

```
[([1], [2], [3, 4]), ([1], [2, 3], [4]), ([1, 2], [3], [4])]
```